# Customize the Pandoc writer for the ConTeXt output format?

Tags: pandoc, writer

I'm currently trying to customize the standard writer built into Pandoc to produce output in the *ConTeXt* format from *Markdown* input. Unfortunately, the [documentation to create a custom writer](https://pandoc.org/custom-writers.html#) found at the Pandoc website is not giving me too much information apart from how to write a custom HTML writer. So, I would like to ask for help with some fundamental ideas:

- What would be the preferrable way to add some (probably) very simple functionality to the ConTeXt writer, e.g.: I would like to rewrite the sequence of characters " - " (in a Markdown document) as another sequence "~-- " (in the resulting ConTeXt document).
- If I understood correctly, I'm supposed to base my custom writer on the standard (built-in) writers... But where can I find these? There doesn't seem to be anything in `/usr/share/pandoc/`(I'm working on Linux).
- The website mentions the *"classic style"* and the *"new style"*. Apart from one obviously being newer, what style am I supposed to use?

I know that these questions may sound rather simple, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of information available beyond the usual basic stuff. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandoc has another feature that is similar to custom writers, called "[Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters)". Filters are quite likely a simpler and better choice in this case: They allow to modify the *internal document representation*. E.g.:

```lua
function Inlines (inlines)
  for i=#inlines, 3, -1 do  -- iterate backwards through the list of inlines
    if inlines[i-2].t == 'Space' and inline[i-1] == pandoc.Str '-' and
       inlines[i].t == 'Space' then
      -- Replace elements with raw ConTeXt
      inlines[i-2] = pandoc.RawInline('context', '~--')
      inlines:remove(i)
      inlines:remove(i-1)
    end
  end
  return inlines
end
```

The above would be used b writing it to a file, and then passing that file to pandoc via `--lua-filters FILENAME.lua`

The documentation for Lua filters is also less sparse and hopefully more approachable than the docs for custom writers.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the helpful answer! I still lack a fundamental understanding as to when it's preferrable to use filters and which tasks are better tackled by writers – but your code almost solved my question. :) There's still one problem: I would like to replace the original sequence ` - ` by a sequence that's **longer** by one character: `~-- `. Unfortunately, that last space is missing in your code – is there a way to *insert* one more *"inline"* into the AST?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I just noticed, my last question can simply be solved by adding the missing SPACE to the replaced string `~-- `. I was afraid this would risk overwriting part of the AST...